# Finding specific pattern of numbers using regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract a specific pattern of numbers using regular expression in Python 3.7. Below are the 4 possible patterns.

Pattern 1 - The length of this pattern is exactly 10 and cannot start with a zero. These consist of only integers. Ex: '1234567890'

Pattern 2 - The length of this pattern is exactly 11 and can start with a zero. These consist of only integers. Ex: '01234567890'

Pattern 3 - The length of this pattern is exactly 11 and cannot start with a zero. There is one space after the 5th number and all other characters are numbers. Ex: '12345 67890'

Pattern 4 - The length of this pattern is exactly 12 and can start with a zero. There is one space after the 6th number and all other characters are numbers. Ex: '012345 67890'

Note - The example pattern example provided is for representation only. The actual set of numbers in my string can be anything. Example: '2345653340' or '034945 85730' or '000000 00000' or '09876543210'.

Below is what I have been trying to attempt. For some reason, they are not returning the desired results. How do I go about this?

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r"(\d)?\d\d\d\d\d(\b)?\d\d\d\d\d")

number1 = regex.findall("number is 1234567890") # For Pattern 1 expected output is '1234567890'
number2 = regex.findall("number is 01234567890") # For Pattern 2 expected output is '01234567890'
number3 = regex.findall("number is 12345 67890") # For Pattern 3 expected output is '12345 67890'
number4 = regex.findall("number is 012345 67890") # For Pattern 4 expected output is '012345 67890'
```

Comment: It would be useful to know what output you get and what you expected instead. You would make it easy for others to help you.

Comment: Try this- `0?\d{10}|0?\d{5}\s\d{5}`. It'll match all the 4 patterns.

Comment: Your Regex is incorrect because it accept 01234 56789 (pattern 3). For patterns that doesn't accept 0 you can not use \d. You must use [123456789] !

Comment: @GulJamalZim there are basically a ton of patterns that can match those numbers, the point is to understand what do you want to be matched.

Comment: @GiovaLomba, I just updated my question to get desired output.

Comment: @Code_Sipra that really helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why does `00000 00000` match? It is 10 digits with a space and start with a zero right? Is that Pattern 3?

Comment: I just fixed my question. It should be '000000 00000' which falls in pattern 4. Thanks for pointing it out @The fourth bird

Answer (score 1):

Regex101 ([link](https://regex101.com/r/u8Ep0x/1)):

```
import re

l = ["number is 1234567890",
"number is 01234567890",
"number is 12345 67890",
"number is 012345 67890",

"number is 912345 67890 - dont match",
"number is 02345 67890 - dont match",
"number is 91234567890 - dont match",
"number is 0234567890 - dont match"]

for s in l:
    m = re.findall(r'\b0\d{5}\s\d{5}\b|\b[1-9]\d{4}\s\d{5}\b|\b0\d{10}\b|\b[1-9]\d{9}\b', s)
    print(m)
```

Prints:

```
['1234567890']
['01234567890']
['12345 67890']
['012345 67890']
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrej Kesely! The examples I gave was for representative purposes only. Sorry if it was confusing. The numbers in my string can be anything. Example: '2345653340' or '034945 85730' or '00000 00000'

Comment: @Code_Sipra Yes, the regex will match any correct number. You can try it in Regex101. `\d` stands for any digit `0-9`

Answer (score 1):

You could use and alternation to match the different requirements. You could use a word boundary `\b` to prevent the number being part of a larger word.

```
\b(?:\d{6} \d{5}|[1-9]\d{4} \d{5}|[1-9]\d{9}|\d{11})\b
```

- `\b` word boundary
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d{6} \d{5}` **Pattern 4** 6 times 0-9, space 5 times 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d{4} \d{5}` **Pattern 3** 1 time 1-9, 4 times 0-9, space, 5 times 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d{9}` **Pattern 1** 1 times 1-9, 9 times 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{11}` **Pattern 2** 11 times 0-9
- `)` Close group
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2AkWxL/2) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/1gkUs4)

Answer (score 1):

Between all the regexes given til now, this one seems the **easiest to write and fastest to run**:

```py
from re import compile
regex = compile(r'\d{11}|[1-9]\d{9}|[1-9]\d{4}\s\d{5}|\d{6}\s\d{5}')
number1 = regex.findall("number is 1234567890")
number2 = regex.findall("number is 01234567890")
number3 = regex.findall("number is 12345 67890") 
number4 = regex.findall("number is 012345 67890")
```

You get the expected results:

```py
>>> number1
'1234567890'
>>> number2
'01234567890'
>>> number3
'12345 67890'
>>> number4
'012345 67890'
```

Answer from Andrej Kesely does: `80` steps. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/u8Ep0x/6)
Answer from The fourth bird does: `44` steps. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2AkWxL/3)
My answer does: `41` steps. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qzu8Qp/3).

Comment: Thanks @GiovaLomba. I believe my question was a little misleading. I just added a note to avoid confusion. The example pattern provided is for representation only. The actual set of numbers in my string can be anything. Example: '2345653340' or '034945 85730' or '00000 00000' or '09876543210'.

Comment: @Code_Sipra I saw it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Looks like this implementation fails for '01111 67890'. The result should be an empty list since it matches pattern 3 conditions.

Comment: @Code_Sipra you are right I updated the regex excluding the leading zeroes and the pattern is again the most efficient one :)

Comment: @Thefourthbird you are right! In fact all the links I've given are evaluated on the same minimal example given by OP.